How to adjust line spacing to fit table cell with MS Word?
Is there a way, other than trial-and-error, that I can get the line spacing in the second column to automatically match the height of the text in the first column?
As in, the first and last lines of both columns line up and everything else is evenly spread vertically?


Line spacing is for text "height", typeface point size; that will not make the column text spread vertically in the way that you indicate in the last paragraph. Please clarify what you wish for.

I’ve described what I wish for: the text in the second column to be spread evenly,  vertically, over the entire height of the column.

Count the number of lines in both columns, take the ratio and apply it to the linespacing?

Possible answer (untested):
Count lines in first column, multiply by text point size => height in points(1)
Count lines in second column(2), multiply by text point size => height in points(2)
Subtract height in points(2) from height in points(1), divide by Count lines in second column(2)
=> add to line height(2)
Possibly needs some adjustment.
